# Rerecording secondary command buffers

Tags: vulkan

I tried the use of secondary command buffers and run into a problem. After resizing my window, both primary and secondary command buffers are rerecorded.
If the secondary command buffers are updated and the primary command buffers, that those contain, do not have been submitted yet, the validation layers throw a

```
Calling vkBeginCommandBuffer() on active CB 0x0x166dbc0 before it has completed. You must check CB fence before this call.
```

error. To fix this, I currently ensure, that all primary command buffers are at least once submitted, before updating the secondary command buffers.

Is there an easier way to avoid this problem, as I waste the rendering of up to 7 frames (number of framebuffers in my swapchain) with this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command buffer must not be still in use when you try to re-record it.
You need to use `VkFence` (or some equivalent: `vkDeviceWaitIdle()` or `vkQueueWaitIdle()`) to make sure it is not.

There's usually lot to do when resizing and it is not expected to be frequent operation, so:

Just use `vkDeviceWaitIdle()` when reacting to the resize event (then recreate all entities that need it).

As for secondary command buffers, there is this counter-intuitive statement in the spec:

> A secondary command buffer is considered to be pending execution from the time its execution is recorded into a primary buffer (via `vkCmdExecuteCommands`) until the final time that primary buffer’s submission to a queue completes.

So reading it literaly it is "pending execution", as soon as it is recorded in primary buffer.

(Might be unintended interpretation by the spec makers... I raised it as [#414](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/414) Issue.)

Comment: That is not the point. The problem occurs after resizing operations are done. It is like resize->submit 1st primary command buffers (6 left) -> vkDeviceIdle -> update secondary commandbuffers: Error message.I called vkDeviceWaitIdle() directly in front of the vkBeginCommandBuffer(), but the problem is, that the other primary command buffers never had been submitted.

Comment: I see, I was in the middle of making some edit that probably covers this case too. (I am also getting some deja vu from this -- I should investigate a bit where I have seen similar problem being written about...)

Comment: Alright, missed this detail. As vkDeviceWaitIdle will not work here, and submitting all primary command buffers is very costly: is there way to put a secondary command buffer from pending execution state to recording state again?

Comment: Apart from the message being displayed does your program work? Reading the layer code, I think doing `vkResetCommandBuffer()` could circumvent the check.

Comment: The code works, but the error message are irritating. `vkResetCommandBuffer` works finde. Wonder why I didn't try it earlier.

Comment: Technically the layers should be writing the same for both (begin does reset implicitly). Would you consider reporting it to the layer repo: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues ?